Prove that if $2n+1$ and $3n+1$ are squares, then $5n+3$ is not a prime where, $n\in \Bbb N$.
I tried to represent the squares with mod 4 but got no useful result.
I also tried the $a^2-b^2$ property but got a quadratic which I couldn't relate.
I noticed if $n$ is a multiple of 3, it solves the case, but I couldn't prove why $n$ should be a multiple of 3.
Here is the exact question:
Prove that if $2n+1$ and $3n+1$ are squares, then $5n+3$ is not a prime where, $n\in \Bbb N$

I guess you're not counting zero as a natural number?

@MartianInvader No, $0$ will not be included.

n doesn't have to be a multiple of $3$; $n $ could be $40$; Cf. OEIS

Hint : $5n+3 = 4(2n+1) - (3n+1)$

 Assuming $2n+1=x^2$ and $3n+1=y^2$ we have $5n+3=4x^2-y^2 = (2x+y)(2x-y)$ and hence $5n+3$ is not a prime.


 The justification for $2x-y\neq 1$ is that if $2x+y=5n+3$, then $4x=5n+4$ implying $n=4k$ and $x=5k+1$. Using these values in $2n+1=x^2$, we get $n=0$.


Would you not need to consider the case where 2x-y=1 a bit closer?

@Jon I placed an edit

Assume $2n + 1 = a^2$ and $3n + 1 = b^2$ for some integers $a$ and $b$.
From $2n + 1 = a^2$, we get $n = \frac{a^2 - 1}{2}$.
Substitute $n$ into $5n + 3$:
$5 \left( \frac{a^2 - 1}{2} \right) + 3 = \frac{5a^2 - 5 + 6}{2} = \frac{5a^2 + 1}{2}$.
Rewrite $5n + 3$ as
$5n + 3 = 4(2n + 1) - (3n + 1) = 4a^2 - b^2$.
Factor $4a^2 - b^2$ as $ (2a - b)(2a + b)$.
Since $2a - b$ and $2a + b$ are both greater than 1 for natural $n$, $5n + 3$ is composite.

Hint: $$5n+3 = 4(2n+1)-(3n+1)$$ Let $x^2 = 2n+1$ and $y^2=3n+1$. We can assume both $x$ and $y$ are positive. Now suppose in $$5n+3 = (2x-y)(2x+y)$$ that $2x-y = 1$ (can you see why?). Now try and prove that $2x+y$ is not a prime.
